# When I try to use parse5-sax-parser and Mocha, I get TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts". How do I fix this error?

Tags: node.js, typescript, mocha.js, html-parsing

Here is the code for the project.

src/index.ts

```
import { SAXParser, StartTag, EndTag } from "parse5-sax-parser"
import fs from "fs"
const parse = (stream: fs.ReadStream): Promise<void> =>{
  const parser = new SAXParser()

  parser.on("startTag", (elem: StartTag)=>{
    if(elem.tagName === "LINK"){
        console.log(elem)
    }
  })

  parser.on("closeTag", (elem: EndTag)=>{
    if(elem.tagName === "LINK"){
        console.log(elem)
    }
  })

  parser.on("text", (text: string) =>{
    console.log(text)
  })

  return new Promise<void>((resolve)=>{
    
    stream.on("end", ()=>{
      console.log("end")
    })

    stream.pipe(parser)
  })
  
}

export default parse
```

.mocharc.json

```
{
    "extension": ["ts"],
    "spec": "test/**/*.spec.ts",
    "require": "ts-node/register"
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "parse-error-testing",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "type":"module",
  "module":"commonjs",
  "directories": {
    "test": "test",
    "lib":"lib"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "compile": "tsc --declaration",
    "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json",
    "prepublish": "npm run compile",
    "test": "nyc --reporter=lcov --reporter=text mocha --reporter-option maxDiffSize=0 "
  },
  "files": [
    "/lib"
  ],
  "author": "stephen.dt.le@gmail.com",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "^4.3.4",
    "@types/mocha": "^10.0.1",
    "chai": "^4.3.7",
    "mocha": "^10.2.0",
    "nyc": "^15.1.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "parse5-sax-parser": "^7.0.0"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "outDir": "./lib",
      "rootDir": "./src",
      "target": "es2022",                                  /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */
      "module": "CommonJS",                                /* Specify what module code is generated. */
      "esModuleInterop": true,                             /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' for type compatibility. */
      "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,            /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */
      "strict": true,                                      /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
      "skipLibCheck": true                                 /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*"],
  }
```

test/test.spec.ts

```
import chai from "chai"
import fs from "fs"
import parse from "../src/index"
const expect = chai.expect
describe("parse5 bug", function(){
    const html_str_1 = fs.createReadStream("./test/1.txt", 'utf8') //For bug replication, just replace this with any HTML stored as a .txt file in the same directory as test.spec.ts
    describe("Attempting to parse", function(){
        it("should parse", function(){
            parse(html_str_1) //When I don't include this line of code, eveything runs just fine
        })
    })
})
```

I ran "npm run test", and that resulted in the error. I tried using "loader": "ts-node/esm" in tsconfig.json, but that just resulted in a new error, that being ReferenceError: exports is not defined in ES module scope. I tried removing "type":"module" and "module":"commonjs", but doing that resulted in another error, that being the following: